# Resize the camera preview to original size when dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a button to open the camera in which I have zoomed my Camera preview but after tacking a picture or skipping that , every time I hit the camera button , the camera preview scaled again and again.
what can I do at the beginning of the code in button code to return the scale to the original size?

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController , UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{
 var cameraView: UIView!
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    
    var selectedPic = 0

 @IBAction func camera1(_ sender: Any) {        
        cameraView = UIView()
        
        selectedPic = 1
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
            imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
            imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false
            imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = self.addOverlay()
            imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = imagePicker.cameraViewTransform.scaledBy(x: 4, y: 4);
    
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func camera2(_ sender: Any) {
        
        cameraView = UIView()
        selectedPic = 2

            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
            imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
            imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false
            imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = self.addOverlay()
            imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = imagePicker.cameraViewTransform.scaledBy(x: 4, y: 4);
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I myself solved the problem by changing the code in the scaling section as below.
I don`t know why but it works fine.

```
 if imagePicker.cameraViewTransform.isIdentity{
            imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = imagePicker.cameraViewTransform.scaledBy(x: 4, y: 4)}
```